# Can I close windows/quit applications directly from the expose interface?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, expose

I find myself periodically closing several windows by accessing them through the expose interface. It's really a pain to enter expose mode, click on a window, close it, and then switch to expose again and repeat. So can I close a window/quit application in the expose interface itself? (just like I can use Cmd+Q to directly close from Cmd+Tab switching interface).

I am using OsX 10.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the (free) application [Better Touch Tool](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/32953/bettertouchtool), you can create a custom gesture to close out windows. Once you assign a gesture to close out a window, use it on any window in Expose and it should close out the window for you (without exiting Expose).

Source: http://hintsforums.macworld.com/showthread.php?t=66483